# Working with ZipInputStream object, how can available() return a 1 but read return a -1?

Tags: java

Guys here is the relevant code...

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(zip.getInputStream(ze));
System.out.println(zis.available());
int count = zis.read(data,0,buffer);
System.out.println(count);
```

I continually get this as output...
1
-1

Now its my understanding that a 1 for available means it isn't at the end of the file and -1 returned from read means it is the end of the file.  How can they both be true?

Comment: SSCCE please, google it for enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

It's only an 'estimate': see the Javadoc. Presumably in this case it is intended to signify that you should do a read to collect the EOS indication. There are very few correct uses of available() and I doubt that this is one of them.

Comment: I don't see anything about an estimate in the javadoc.  The only thing it says is "Programs should not count on this method to return the actual number of bytes that could be read without blocking"  Which doesn't seem to apply here

Comment: @Max I quote from http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available(): 'Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.'

Answer (score 0):

check if the value of 'buffer' passed to read method is less than or equal to 0 ?